# Using bash, how can I remove the extensions of all files in a specific directory?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I want to keep the files but remove their extensions. The files do not have the same extension to them. My end goal is to remove all their extensions and change them to one single extension of my choice. I have the second part down.

My code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter the directory: "
read path
            #Remove all extensions
find $path -type f -exec mv '{}' '{}'.extension \; #add desired extension
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need an external command `find` for this, but do it in `bash` alone. The script below removes the extension from all the files in the folder `path`.

```sh
for file in "$path"/*; do
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue
    mv "$file" "${file%.*}"
done
```

The reason for using `[ -f "$file" ]` is only for a safety check. The glob expression "$path"/* might end up in no files listed, in that case the `mv` command would fail as there are no files. The `[ -f "$file" ] || continue` condition safeguards this by exiting the loop when the `$file` variable is empty in which the `[ -f "$file" ]` returns a failure error code. The `||` when used in a compound statement will run if the previous command fails, so when `continue` is hit next, the for loop is terminated.

If you want to add a new extension just do

```sh
mv "$file" "${file%.*}.extension"
```

Comment: Does "[ -f "$file" ] || continue" check if its a file?

Comment: @Jaspreet: That is a glob pattern to list all files in the current folder. You might want to read through [Bash - Glob Patterns](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns)

Comment: `for file in * ; do [ -f "$file" ] && { echo "${file%.*}"; } ; done` -- TEST the script before renaming all your files :)

Comment: superfluous OR condition `|| continue` can be replaced with a simpler AND `&& { }` as per my previous comment

Answer (score 1):

This could also be a way

```
for i in `find . -type f `;do  filename=`ls $i | cut -f 2 -d "."`;  mv $i ./$filename.ext; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the below. It uses find and awk with system() to remove the extension:

```
find . -name "*" -type f|awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"}{print $2}'|awk 'BEGIN{FS="."}{system("mv "$0" ./"$1"")}'
```

example:

```
[root@puppet:0 check]# ls -lrt
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Oct  5 13:49 abc.ext
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Oct  5 13:49 something.gz
[root@puppet:0 check]# find . -name "*" -type f|awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"}{print $2}'|awk 'BEGIN{FS="."}{system("mv "$0" ./"$1"")}'
[root@puppet:0 check]# ls -lrt
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Oct  5 13:49 abc
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Oct  5 13:49 something
```

also if you have a specific extension that you want to add to all the files, you may modify the command as below:

```
find . -name "*" -type f|awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"}{print $2}'|awk 'BEGIN{FS=".";ext=".png"}{system("mv "$0" ./"$1ext"")}'
```