# What does "${file%.*}" mean in bash

Tags: bash, git-bash

I'm reading through [Using bash, how can I remove the extensions of all files in a specific directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586447/using-bash-how-can-i-remove-the-extensions-of-all-files-in-a-specific-directory). The accepted answer is:

```
for file in "$path"/*; do
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue
    mv "$file" "${file%.*}"
done
```

I don't understand the line:

```
    mv "$file" "${file%.*}"
```

despite reading through a number of resources such as http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns

What is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a form of [Parameter Expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).

`"${file%.*}"` means "Variable `file` minus everything after and including the right-most period."
`${file%%.*}"` would reference the *left-most* period.

This is a combination of the `${%}` operator and a [Glob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).

edit: I had a hard time with this "substring removal" expansion until I noticed that `#` is to the 'left' of `$`, while `%` is to the right. Parameter Expansions are an essential ingredient in the use of Bash as a scripting language; I recommend practice.

Answer (score 3):

Check the documentation for [parameter substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)

> **`${var%Pattern}, ${var%%Pattern}`**
>
> **`${var%Pattern}`** Remove from `$var` the shortest part of `$Pattern` that
>   matches the back end of `$var`.
>
> **`${var%%Pattern}`** Remove from `$var` the longest part of `$Pattern` that
>   matches the back end of `$var`.

It's basically saying to populate `$file` with the full filename and then remove everything after the `%` with the shortest match for `.*`, which would be any extension.

```
# assume you want to convert myfile.txt to myfile
$file="myfile.txt"
# move the current name to the current name excluding the shortest match of .* = .txt
mv "$file" "${file%.*}"
# expands to
mv "myfile.txt" "myfile"
```